# Unit Test - toEqual Object vs Array

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I know this is a silly question but I cannot for the life of me figure out why. I am new to testing and new to JavaScript so apologies in advance.

I have the following test.

```
describe('initialized from copy job functionality', () => {
    it('should initialize the constructor based on production selection', () => {
        spyOn(MockWizardService, 'loadViewsForWizardSteps').and.returnValue(q.resolve({
                templates
        }));
        controller.Init();
        scope.$digest();
        expect(controller.templatesToBeDisplayed).toEqual(templatesAll);
    });
```

These are my templates.

```
let templates = [
    'views/wizards/create_test/sortStep.html',
];
let templatesAll = [
    'views/wizards/create_test/general.html',
    templates,
    'views/wizards/create_test/summary.html'
];
```

`templates` will change that's why I have it in that format. 
This is the error I get.

> Expected $[1] = Object({templates: [ 'views/wizards/create_test/sortStep.html' ] }) to equal [ 'views/wizards/create_test/sortStep.html' ].

I know I need to change the way templates is in templatesAll but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you fix it by changing your `expect` ?

```
expect(controller.templatesToBeDisplayed.templates).toEqual(templatesAll)
```

Maybe try to be a bit more explicit about your question. Have you noticed that it returns an `object` containing an array `templates` ?
Your test is not very explicit because a lot of code is hidden inside your controller. Try to test small function, and maybe if you show us the code we'll be more helpful.

Good luck :)